# Showing error while trying to run mediaPlayer in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have done the below code for running a music in background of activity, using asyncTask.

```
 public class BackgroundSound extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
 {
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(BiographyActivity.this, R.raw.test_cbr); 
  player.setLooping(true); // Set looping 
  player.setVolume(100,100); 
      player.start(); 
      return null;      }
  }


@Override
protected void onResume() 
{ super.onResume();
  mBackgroundSound.execute(null); }


@Override
protected  void onPause()
  {  super.onPause();
    mBackgroundSound.cancel(true);   }
```

But its showing error for execute method inside onResume:

```
The method execute(Void[]) is ambiguous for the type BiographyActivity.BackgroundSound
```

Comment: Since you are not dealing with any UI changes in your AsyncTask you can just use Runnable / Thread instead

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend not use async task for playing background music, instead you can use prepareAsync method from media player class which will itself load music in background.

**Here is my implementation:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class BiographyActivity extends Activity implements OnPreparedListener {

private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.media_player_activity);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.test);
    try {
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        afd.close();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}

private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that View[] is ambiguous, Try execute(Void[3]) or execute();